# How to retrieve data from local disk C (cannot be mounted) using Ubuntu 12.04 live USB?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have an [Acer Aspire 4740](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_Aspire_Notebook#Aspire_notebook_models) with Windows 7 Home Premium installed in it. This laptop has a local disk C of 90 GB (where Windows 7 is installed) and disk D 270 GB in it. Last week I suddenly could not boot into Windows. I tried to recover it using cmd, but I failed.

There are important documents on it, and I need to access them. So I'm using a [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) [live USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB) (which I'm using "try only" version) to access the local disk C. However I can only mount disk D but cannot mount local disk C. When I double click on disk C, it says:

> Cannot mount, because it is in pending operation

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried to mount it read only? (see eg here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/296331/how-to-mount-a-hard-disk-as-read-only-from-the-terminal); if you need to find partition ids http://serverfault.com/questions/190685/whats-the-best-way-to-get-info-about-currently-unmounted-drives

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing, is that the drive is still marked as active from windows, so the "in use" marker is set to yes, more or less.

I found a post about this from another forum, with the following workaround:

> The only current solution I have at this time is Symantec Partition
>   Magic
>
> > and that involves a work around. For this to work, I have to create a 
> >     temporary Primary partition, then (2) mark said temporary Primary partition 
> >     Active and then (3) delete said Primary partition - this will leave all prior 
> >     drives uneffected and no drives Active on the hard drive
> >
> > One side effect of this work around - Partition Magic will alter a Windows 
> >     Multiboot "boot.ini" file after any partition is deleted

I know that this does not include the ubuntu live disk, but none-the-less, if it works, it works, right? Let me know if this helps you.

Referenced Post: [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/59517-45-need-unmark-active-hard-drive)